# Apache Beam Python Program writing 0 kb files?

Tags: python, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a apache beam program written in python, which basically reads a input file, process some input and filters the outputs to different taggedoutput and then write those output to different files.

Now those different taggedoutput can be empty due to any reason and when the scripts writes those tagges output to files, the files are of 0kb.

```
So my questions is,
1. What can I avoid creating 0kb files if taggedoutput is empty? 
2. If is good ETL concept not to create 0kb files if taggedoutput is empty.
```

Some work friends gave arguments like it is not a best ETL practice to create 0kb file.

Comment: show your pipeline code

Comment: What sink are you using to write? Are you writing to GCS?

Comment: Yes, and even if I write to local it also write 0kb files